# Cannot load the same module, in the same process, multiple times using imp.load_module

Tags: python, python-import, python-multiprocessing, python-module

I'm trying to import `mymodule.py` in the constructor of C class in order each new instance of the C class to use its own mymodule when the `f` method is called as a new process using multiprocessing module.

Please review the code below:

**mymodule.py**

```
import random
n = random.randint(0, 1000)
```

**mp_test.py**

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
import imp

class C(object):

    def __init__(self, c='*'):
        self.mm=imp.load_module('mm', *imp.find_module('mymodule'))
        self.c = c

    def f(self):
        print self.c, id(self.mm), id(self.mm.n), self.mm.n

def main():

    p = []
    for _ in range(2):
        p.append(mp.Process(target=C().f))
        p[-1].start()

    time.sleep(1)
    print ''

    p0 = mp.Process(target=C(c='>').f)
    p1 = mp.Process(target=C(c='>').f)
    p0.start()
    p1.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

After the execution of the `mp_test.py` the stdout result is:

```
funk@linux:~/mp_test# python mp_test.py
* 140679674677800 94828316092856 40
* 140679674677800 94828316835224 486

> 140679674677800 94828317211688 763
> 140679674677800 94828317211688 763
```

As expected the following piece of code creates to different instances of `mymodule` and consequently two different random numbers are generated:

```
    p = []
    for _ in range(2):
        p.append(mp.Process(target=C().f))
        p[-1].start()

* 140679674677800 94828316092856 40
* 140679674677800 94828316835224 486
```

When the `start()` methods are called as follows `mymodule` is not imported twice and consequently the random numbers are the same...

```
    p0 = mp.Process(target=C(c='>').f)
    p1 = mp.Process(target=C(c='>').f)
    p0.start()
    p1.start()

> 140679674677800 94828317211688 763
> 140679674677800 94828317211688 763
```

Your ideas please...!

**Edit**

zwer's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51083991/2194843) resolves the issue:

**Code correction**

```
    # ERROR self.mm=imp.load_module('mm', *imp.find_module('mymodule'))
    self.mm=imp.load_module('mm_' + str(uuid.uuid4()), *imp.find_module('mymodule'))
```

**Updated results**

```
funk@linux:~/mp_test# python -O mp_test.py
* 139813126327944 94540189500648 396
* 139813126447184 94540189500504 491

> 139813126447296 94540189500432 847
> 139813126447240 94540189500384 389
```

**Note** that the 1st column of the latest results that represents the `id(self.mm)` is always different!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is not directly linked with multiprocessing, you do the module loading in the same process before you attempt to run the `f()` method as a separate process. This results in module caching so the next time you try to import it, Python gives you a cached instance where the random part doesn't get executed again.

Why you get different results between the first and the second case is because you immediately spawn a process (and therefore fork/split the context) after you create your `C` instance while you don't give that luxury to your second approach where you first instantiate your `C` instances and then start new processes - e.g. if you were to do:

```
p0 = mp.Process(target=C(c='>').f)
p0.start()
p1 = mp.Process(target=C(c='>').f)
p1.start()
```

You would get the expected result, too.

That being said, if you want to load the same module, in the same process, multiple times while avoiding caching you have to give it a different name when loading, something like:

```
class C(object):

    load_counter = 0

    def __init__(self, c='*'):
        self.mm=imp.load_module('mm' + str(C.load_counter), *imp.find_module('mymodule'))
        C.load_counter += 1
        self.c = c
```

Or do the module loading in the spawned process (**after** calling `start()` on it). If you just want a different result while keeping the cached module (i.e. without re-evaluation) - place the module logic in a function and then execute the function instead.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I verify that by giving a different name when trying to load the module I get the expected results!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are on Unix system like Linux for example, where default strategy to create a subprocess is [forking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)).
Subprocess inherits the execution state and memory state of it's parent, including imported Python modules. You are correct when you say that `mymodule` is not imported for the second time.

You actually want to wrap the code in `mymodule` with a function:

```
import random

def get_random():
    return random.randint(0, 1000)
```

and then call it from your `mp_test.C.f()` method:

```
def f(self):
    print self.c, id(self.mm), id(self.mm.get_random()), self.mm.get_random()
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! zwer's suggestion resolves the issue.